# raster2pgsql command line issue (Windows 10) - ERROR: syntax error at or near "raster2pgsql"

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, sql, postgis-raster

I'm using the OsGeo4W64 shell that comes with QGIS (I'm using Windows 10) and have managed to log into my postgres database. However I'm looking to import a raster into a new table, and all roads seem to point to raster2pgsql.

I've installed postGIS through the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` and `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;` commands in my database and I have installed postGIS 3.1.1 through the 'Stack Builder' tool without issue.

Now when I connect to a database and type in `raster2pgsql;`, or if I type a full command like `raster2pgsql -s 4326 -t 1x1 -f DN -I -Y D:/one.tif rasterSchema.RasterName > raster.sql ;` , I get a syntax `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "raster2pgsql"` . I assume it's some kind of pathing issue?

I actually get the same result with shp2pgsql too...
I'm quite new to postgres and don't really know what to do about this

[image: Command Line Error:]

Comment: raster2pgsql is a console program, to be run in a shell. It is not an SQL command.

Comment: I got the following to work:    `cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin`  then 
`raster2pgsql.exe -s 4326 -t 1x1 -f DN -I -Y D:/1.tif rasterSchema.RasterName > D:/raster.sql` . It takes a fair bit of time though